# Error Getting Device Information on Different Android Hardware/OS

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I'm using the following plugin on my Cordova project:

> com.vliesaputra.deviceinformation

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var deviceInfo = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation');
deviceInfo.get(GotDeviceInfo, function () {
    alert('error');
}

function GotDeviceInfo(result) {
    var data = JSON.parse(result);
    alert(data.phoneNo);
    alert(data.simNo);
}
```

On my Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F (Android 5.0) I'm getting accurate information on the phone and sim numbers, but on my TomTom PRO 8275 (Android 4.3) I get `TM.ERROR` for both values. I assume TM means TelephonyManager, but apart from that, I have no definite reason why this works on one Android device and not on the other.

I have activated sims in both devices and have tested mobile data which again works just fine. So I know the sim is working in both devices. Is it just the hardware doesn't support it? The OS version?

**Does anyone have any definitive solutions or ideas on how to get this to work or at least why it doesn't?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's because the manufacturer does not provide these values to be accessable by the android framework. Several android functionalities are manufacturer related and could return different results on different devices.

Comment: I assumed this might be the case. Any definitive evidence?

Comment: not for your case, but there are different ways to access the phone hw information and I think cordova is just using one of them. But your phone is providing this information on another way cordova is not aware of.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the best answer I got. ;-)